# Else block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I just started learning ruby, but there's something I noticed.
In JavaScript the else block isn't really needed. So you can do something like

```
if (condition){
    // do something
    return
  }

//do something else
return
```

instead of

```
if (condition){
    // do something
    return
  } else {
  //do something else
  return
}
```

is this possible in Ruby ?

Comment: Yes. It's possible, In a nutshell, all programming languages are similar. So, You don't have to define (else) in JavaScript or Ruby or any other languages. until you really need to.

So, You can do it like that In Ruby:

` if condition
#Do Something
end`
or

`if condition
#Do Something
else
#Do something else
end`

Comment: Those two snippets are not the same.  In the first one you need a `return` if you want `//do something else` to not execute.  Same thing in Ruby or other programming languages.

Comment: yes you can if statement does not terminate method or script https://www.rubyguides.com/ruby-tutorial/ruby-if-else/

Comment: A few other notes as you are learning. Ruby has an expression called `unless` which is equivalent to "if not". `unless` should not be used with an else statement per [Style Guidelines](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#no-else-with-unless).  Also ruby supports what it calls "modifiers" where the if statement can trail the expression inline so for example you can type `do_something if condition` and `do_something` will only be called if the condition is met.(`unless` can be used the in the same fashion)

Comment: Of course, with the caveat that the two structures you show are very different things. It might make sense to spin through a tutorial, though, rather than asking questions like this on SO. Not criticizing the question, but this kind of thing is readily self-answerable in a few minutes in code or docs.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Also, it would help future programmers, if you could explain what, *precisely*, is unclear to you about the syntax documentation. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't stumble over the same problems you did. Essentially, you would make the world a better place, and who wouldn't want that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use `if` without `else` in Ruby.

Here are some examples

```rb
class Demo
  def example1
    if condition
      do_something
    end
    continue
  end

  def example2
    do_something if condition # as modifier
    continue
  end

  def example3
    do_something unless condition # syntactic sugar for if !(condition)
    continue
  end
end
```

For a full tutorial please have a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm).

Please keep in mind, that `example1` is (sometimes) concidered a bad coding style by [the Ruby Style Guide](https://rubystyle.guide/#if-as-a-modifier).